# Do C++ modules make unnamed namespaces redundant?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++-modules, unnamed-namespace

C++20 introduced modules. Any symbol that is not exported in a module has module-internal linkage. While unnamed namespaces provide a mechanism to make definitions inside an unnamed namespace have file-internal linkage. Does this mean unnamed namespaces will become useless in future when modules become common practice in C++ community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: since (many) compilers see just one translation unit at a time, it’s still useful for **optimization** to indicate that an entity cannot be used in any other.  It also avoids the possibility of accidental **collisions** between module units (even if those should be less likely than with broader codebases).

Comment: I believe most people will go down the "one-module-per-cpp-file" route.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li - You believe wrong. One of the most compelling reasons for introducing modules was the ability to organize multiple logically related translation units together.